Unable to specify "container" width for bullet chart - results in overflow/scrolling behavior
I have a simple bullet chart, but when trying to set the width to "container", within spec, it seems to overflow within the container, presumably because of labels. Is there a way around this, either by specifying labelWidth, or another approach?
Pink rectangle shows the area that is being clipped (i.e. you'll need to scroll)

"spec": { 
    "width": "container",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {
        "type": "quantitative",
        "scale": {"nice": false},
        "title": null
      }
    },
    "layer": [{...

Open the Chart in the Vega Editor

See the limitations section under the documentation:
https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/size.html#specifying-responsive-width-and-height
Limitations:
This responsive mode is available only for single view or layer specifications.
Vega listens to the window.resize event to update plot size from container size. This should cover many use cases.
However, if you change the container size programmatically (e.g., you build a custom divider view), you’ll need to trigger window.resize manually.
In a modern browser, you can do: window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));.
If you use javascript you can obtain the width of your div or page etc with a function and then set this in your spec.

@APB Reports provides a good answer. I also come across this issue, you have to adjust the padding of your view and the width of your marks (more so than normal).
Here is my example: Bullet Chart - Vega-Lite

You can also achieve responsive behaviours in PowerBI's Deneb by multiplying marks or other elements by the container height and width:
Config:
{
"padding": {
    "left": 20,
    "right": 20,
    "top": 20,
    "bottom": 20
  }
}

"dx": {"expr": "width * - 0.01"},
"dy": {"expr": "height * 0.01"}

